SwiftUI custom Binding causing unexpected rendering
While investigating performance issues in an app I'm working on, I noticed that a view that contains a custom binding will always be rendered when its parent is rendered, even when the state that triggered the parent to render has nothing to do with the binding itself. Example below:
struct Parent: View {
    @State var text = "text"
    @State var bool = false

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        VStack {
            CustomBindingChild(value: Binding<String>(
                get: {
                    text
                },
                set: { newValue in
                    text = newValue
                }
            ))
            BindingChild(value: $text)
            Divider()
            Text("\(bool)")
            Button("Toggle bool") {
                bool.toggle()
            }
            Button("Change text") {
                text = text == "text" ? "text 2" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomBindingChild: View {
    @Binding var value: String

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(value)
    }
}

struct BindingChild: View {
    @Binding var value: String

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(value)
    }
}

With the setup above, if you tap the "Change text" button all three views are printed, as I would expect. If you tap the "Toggle bool" button, on the other hand, the parent view and the custom binding view are printed and I expect only the parent to do so.
To circumvent this issue I created my own implementation of what I'm calling a StableBinding:
@propertyWrapper
struct StableBinding<Value: Equatable>: Equatable {
    typealias Getter = () -> Value
    typealias Setter = (Value) -> Void

    private var getter: Getter
    private var setter: Setter

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { return getter() }
        nonmutating set { self.setter(newValue) }
    }

    var projectedValue: Self { self }

    init(get: @escaping Getter, set: @escaping Setter) {
        self.getter = get
        self.setter = set
    }

    init(_ binding: Binding<Value>) {
        self.getter = { binding.wrappedValue }
        self.setter = { newValue in
            binding.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }

    static func == (lhs: StableBinding<Value>, rhs: StableBinding<Value>) -> Bool {
        lhs.getter() == rhs.getter()
    }
}

The fact that it implements the Equatable protocol ensures that it doesn't cause the view that's using it to be rendered every time it's evaluated.
My questions are two:

Is there a reason behind Swift's custom binding behaves like this?
Is there a problem in my approach? I've tested it and couldn't find any but it would be really disappointing to find out that I missed something obvious after it hits production.


Gus, can you please edit your code and fix your view Parent as it is not dependent on @State bool.  You might just insert a Text("Bool: \(bool)") in the body.

With the setup you provided, if I tap the Toggle bool button, nothing happens.

@CouchDeveloper bool is a state there so the view is dependent on it regardless of whether it uses it in the body or not. Maybe I didn't quite get the point of your suggestion, can you elaborate please?

@AndreiG. do you mean nothing changes in the UI? Cause if so, that's intended. The idea is to observe the logs in XCode's console.

As also stated by Andrei, if you change  @State bool your Parent.body will not be called. As a consequence, your observed issue where CustomBindingChild's body will be unnecessarily invoked cannot be observed. You are right though, that CustomBindingChild's body is called, for whatever reason, even though CustomBindingChild is not dependent on it. So, in order to make sure, your Parent.body will be called, just insert Text("\(bool)")in order to make Parent dependent on @State bool. Only after this, we can observe the issue you are talking about. ;)

On a side note, this is an excellent question. However, a correct answer is surprisingly challenging. It requires knowledge how SwiftUI performs its View updates involving Bindings. Bindings are not just a struct with a getter and a setter and comparing closures is not possible directly. They also carry a transaction object, which is crucial in certain use cases with animations. Your custom binding might break this. Alternatively, we might consider to extend SwiftUI.Binding making it conform to Equatable. Again, this might cause unknown side effects, thus it is generally not recommended.

A potential problem in your custom binding is, that you assume, the binding values are associated to the same view identity.  However, your equality function does not check this. The questions is, does SwiftUI only call the equality operator for the binding values whose views are the same identity? I suspect, this is not always the case and then your custom binding fails to work as intended.

In my case, nothing was changing anywhere - not in the UI and not in the console. I do see console output when tapping  Change text button, but nothing when tapping Toggle bool button.

I don't see any dependency on the bool anywhere, so what would toggling achieve if it isn't used in any logic?

Is your code/setup supposed to have BindingChild(value: $text) or rather BindingChild(value: $bool) and then maybe in BindingChild struct, the binding should be @Binding var bool: Bool?

Thanks both of you, you are right and I was missing the bool in the body. I've fixed it now. @AndreiG. to your last comment no, the idea is to show that the CustomBindingChild will be be redrawn even though non of its dependencies have changed.

I think I understand what's happening, though not sure if I will explain it right. When using a direct binding to a state (using the $ sign), SwiftUI can establish a relation between a view identity and the value of the state and decide whether it needs to be reinitialized or not. A custom binding is basically a computed property, which may do away with the convenience offered by the direct state binding.

There's also the fact that Parent's body needs to be reinitialized since the bool value is changed AND displayed in the body of Parent, forcing a "recomputing" of the computed property in the body.
You can check this by moving the Text("\(bool)") and the Toggle bool button in another struct like BindingChild (by passing a second binding) and toggling it (and displaying it) there. You'll notice that although bool value changes in the parent, because it is not displayed in the parent, the CustomBindingChild will not be changed.

I added some comments above, I will summarize here again alongside some code.
Is there a reason behind Swift's custom binding behaving like this?
Unlike a @State which allows SwiftUI to understand if the view is the same or distinct (and needs a reinit) based on the state's value, a custom binding behaves more like a computed property, even though it may change values in a state in its setter function.
This may be easier to visualize if you move the custom binding outside the body:
struct Parent: View {
    @State private var text = "text"
    @State var bool = false
    
    private var customBinding: Binding<String> { Binding( // <-- Here, the custom binding is basically a computed property
            get: {
                text
            },
            set: { newValue in
                    text = newValue
            }
    )}
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        
        VStack {
            CustomBindingChild(value: customBinding) // <-- Here, note the lack of the $ sign - a giveaway it's not a direct binding to a state
            
        }
    //... rest of struct code left out


Also, and I am not sure if I am entirely accurate here, I think the custom binding is being recreated each time the parent view's body is re-evaluated.
So if the parent's view body wouldn't need to be re-evaluated, the custom binding wouldn't be recreated and the child view wouldn't be reinitialized. We can test this by moving the display of bool value elsewhere than parent's body, like one of the other structs.
So in Parent:
//...
BindingChild(value: $text, bool: $bool) // <-- Here, pass a second parameter to BindingChild
Divider()
// Text("\(bool)") <-- Here, comment out this line
//...

Then, in BindingChild:
struct BindingChild: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    @Binding var bool: Bool // <-- add the bool as a second parameter and call it from parent using BindingChild(value: $text, bool: $bool)
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(value)
        Text("Bool value in BindingChild: \(bool)") // <-- Display the value of bool in the BindingChild body
    }
}

You'll notice that although the toggle bool button is still in parent and changing a state value in Parent, because we're not displaying the value in the Parent's body, the customBinding will not need to be re-evaluated since Paren't body will not need to re-evaluated.
So I think you were on the right track by conforming to the Equatable protocol, which would allow SwiftUI to establish whether CustomBindingChild needs to be re-evaluated or not when using a custom binding, but your stable binding may be unnecessarily complex. See details below.
Is there a problem in my approach?
Given the details above, conforming to Equatable is not a problem in itself, but considering that you could achieve what you want as follows:
struct CustomBindingChild: View, Equatable { // <-- add Equatable
    @Binding var value: String
    
    static func == (lhs: CustomBindingChild, rhs: CustomBindingChild) -> Bool { // <-- conform to Equatable
        lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Text(value)
    }
}

I'll leave it up to you to decide whether or not your StableBinding approach is a problem or not, based on your specific needs for it.
